# How to add Binary Variable with condition in LP

Tags: linear-programming, optimization

#### Notation

- $\text{src}_{h,s},\text{dst}_{h,s},\text{ch}_{h,s}$ are constants.
- $a_{h,s},x_{i,j,s}$ are binary variables.
- $\text{wt}_{h,s}$ are continuous variables.

#### Problem

\begin{align}\min.&\qquad\sum_{h \in H}\sum_{s\in S}(\text{src}_{h,s}+\text{ch}_{h,s}+\text{dst}_{h,s}+\text{wt}_{h,s})\times a_{h,s}\\\text{s.t.}&\qquad{\forall i,j\in H,\,\forall s\in S}:\text{wt}_{j,s}\geq((\text{src}_{i,s}+\text{ch}_{i,s}+\text{wt}_{i,s})-\text{src}_{j,s})\times x_{i,j,s}\end{align}

Now $x_{i,j,s} = 1$ only when vehicle $i$ charges before vehicle $j$. ([Finding minimum time for vehicle to reach to its destination](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/finding-minimum-time-for-vehicle-to-reach-to-its-destination)) for reference.

Vehicle $i$ charges before $j$ only when $\text{src}_{i,s} < \text{src}_{j,s}$ so how could I force $x_{i,j,s} = 1$ when this condition meets?

Comment: If $src$ are constants, then you know in advance whether $i$ charges before $j$, and you can just force $x_{ijs} = 1$ in this case (via a constraint or via treating it like a constant) — or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: In that case I will write it as an answer in case it is useful to future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the $\text{src}$ are constants, you know in advance whether $i$ charges before $j$, and you can just force $x_{ijs}=1$ in this case (via a constraint or by treating it like a constant).

Answer (score 9):

Add two indicator constraints:

- when $x_{i,j,s} = 1$, the condition must be true ($i$ charges before $j$)
- when $x_{i,j,s} = 0$, the condition must be false ($i$ charges after $j$)

Most commercial solvers have simple APIs that allow you to add indicator constraints directly, without reformulation. For example, here's the documentation for Gurobi's [addGenConstrIndicator](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_addgenconstrindic.html) function.

Comment: Here is an earlier OR.SE post on using indicator constraints, with answers focusing on a couple of different packages: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/231/when-to-use-indicator-constraints-versus-big-m-approaches-in-solving-mixed-int